# Select dynamic elements is not displayed is materializecss modal

Tags: materialize, svelte

When I try to add options element to select in Svelte, using materializecss, the select shows no elements. I listed the exported option elements (the binded data) in a

- 

list and also I can see the elements in the console/elements window. Non dynamically added the elements displays perfectly. Why is it?

The modal code sample:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" style="overflow: hidden; width: 80%">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Add a new locationName</h4>
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <select bind:value={locationName.languageId} label="label goes here">
      {#each languages as listItem}
        <option value={listItem.id}>
          {listItem.name}
        </option>
      {/each}
    </select>
    <ol>
      {#each languages as listItem}
        <li>{listItem.name}</li>
      {/each}
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide code showcasing the problem.

Comment: I completed my post with the code sample. The first static select works perfectly, the dynamic does not. And I displayed the element in a list which appears in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is not with materialize as it's just a styling library. My suspect is the data you are providing is missing some fields.
Please refer to this REPL and check if you are providing the data with same schema.
https://svelte.dev/repl/cba91d7ceb6c4ae48c9c2ace8f916be9?version=3.48.0

Comment: This REPL inserted works. The schema is correct, I use. The main difference I use async GET to retrieve languages list.  In the console/Elements tab I can find the whole select element with the options of my languages items.  Just the displayed Select is empty.

Comment: No it is not asynch problem, because this demo shows there is no problem with svelte select.  https://svelte.dev/repl/cf379d65b38a41258b6cfe3a41b74df2?version=3.48.0

Comment: the problem must be that your provided id is not in list.

Comment: Yes, because I did not find a proper fake API. But the dynamic select works without matrializecss framework, as the above link presents.